# Is there a way to follow a redirect url while doing integration testing in grails?

Tags: grails, integration-testing, grails-2.2

I am using grails 2.2

An integration test looks like this

```
reservationController.params["participant"] = ["firstName": "Hello", "lastName": "Hello", "gender": "MALE", 'phone': '1234567890','email': 'john@doe.com']

def mm = reservationController.save(m.sale.id)
```

Inside the save method of reservation contoller is a redirect at the end

```
    redirect(action: "referral", id: sale.id)
```

It seems like when i run integration test, after calling save it will not follow the redirect to 'referral'. When i add a breakpoint after reservationController.save() and then inspect reservationController.response.redirectedUrl then it shows the redirect url but it doesnt go to the redirected url.

Is there a way to follow the redirect url? i.e when i call .save on reservation controller it will complete the save method and also go to the redirected url and only it will return the model that the redirected url returns.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: "Is there a way to follow the redirect url?" - In a functional test there is.  The fact that you are invoking `reservationController.save(m.sale.id)` suggests this is not a functional test.

Comment: this is integration test.

Comment: i ended up calling the redirect method manually. is there a way to ask you question directly jeff?

Comment: "is there a way to ask you question directly jeff?" - Yes, I am happy to help.  You can send a note to brownj at objectcomputing dot com or info at grails dot org.

Comment: Thank you Jeff. I will do that.